# DataBinding between DataSet and DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, dataset, bindingsource

I currently have a DataGridView on a form which I want to use with a DataTable in a DataSet, populated from a SQlite database (using System.Data.SQlite).

So, I have a DataAdapter between the database and DataSet and can set the DataGridView data source directly as the DataTable. This displays fine.

My question is this:
Why would I want to use a Binding Source here? Many tutorials have said you can use it or not. But is there any use for it, other than adding an extra step?

Also, if I want the database to be updated when the DataGridView is changed, how can this be done? Is the DataSet automatically updated - so I just need to tell the DataAdapter to update? Or is there where a binding source is useful?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else searching for this, I found a good description of why to use a Binding Source [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480734.aspx).

Similarly, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx) explains saving/restoring changes made in the DataGridView.

Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you would have to call `GetChanges` on the `DataSet`, and then insert/update/delete the records.